# What's the best MVVM way to expose a 'add new item' sentinel in an items control?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Say I have a `TabControl` that is presenting a collection of `Foo` objects (each through a `FooViewModel`). At the end of the list of tab items, I want a faux tab item that doesn't model anything, but which creates a new model item and adds it to the collection when clicked.

If the concept isn't clear, a real example is the tabs in Internet Explorer. It has `n+1` tab items: `n` which have page content, and the last one which adds a new 'real' tab.

What's the correct way (if any) to model this type of interaction in MVVM? The options I've thought of are:

- Make it part of the view model. At the end of the `IEnumerable<FooViewModel> Foos` collection that the control is bound to, add a 'new item' sentinel and build the 'am I a real foo or a new foo sentinel' logic into the view model.
- Make it wholly part of the view. Re-template (and/or subclass) `TabControl` to present all the real items and then also a button which invokes the command to create and insert a new item.

The first option feels wrong at first, like it's leaking view details into the view model (it seems quite likely that 'add a new `Foo`' is a general command, and some view may not want it invokable from the tab list at all). But it does make some amount of sense, because for the initialization process I'll already need to model a 'semi-constructed `Foo`', so a model of a 'not-yet-existing `Foo`' doesn't seem so far off.

The second part seems like a lot of work and also easy to screw up (assuming the desire is for it to look and feel like the other tabs).

But I'm new to MVVM; surely this comes up pretty often. Maybe I'm missing something entirely. What's the traditional way to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of the key tenants of the MVVM pattern are:

- **Testability** - by making your view as simple as possible, by moving logic into your view-model, you increase the amount of logic you can test via unit testing.
- **Designer-Support** - a mock view-model can be used to supply design-time data to your view.

Which of your suggestions best fulfills the above? I would say option (1). You can write unit tests to ensure that the last item in the list is always a 'sentinel' item.

In order to "build 'am I a real foo or a new foo sentinel' logic into the view model.", you can simply use typed DataTemplates.

Comment: Marking this as the answer even though I'm not completely satisfied. I think there just is no good answer. The counter-point to the two arguments that you make is that, if option (2) were chosen, then the testable/designable part would just be the 'make a new item' command. How that command is triggered would be purely part of the view, so those points don't apply. But, thanks for the input. I think I'm going to try going down this road, for now.

Answer (score 1):

It might be simpler just to retemplate the TabControl and add add a faux tab or button to the right of the tabs.

Basic example:

```
<Window x:Class="ContextMenuSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush"
                         Color="#FFF" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidBorderBrush"
                         Color="#888" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush"
                         Color="#888" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBorderBrush"
                         Color="#AAA" />

        <Style  TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
                    Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
                    Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                        <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TabPanel Name="HeaderPanel"
                                      Grid.Row="0"
                                      Panel.ZIndex="1"
                                      Margin="0,0,4,-1"
                                      IsItemsHost="True"
                                      KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                                      Background="Transparent" />
                            <Button Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Content="Add new" />
                            <Border Name="Border"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
                                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="1"
                                    CornerRadius="2"
                                    KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
                                    KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                                    KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2">
                                <ContentPresenter Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                                                  Margin="4"
                                                  ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                     Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                        Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Border"
                                        Property="BorderBrush"
                                        Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Item 1" />
            <TabItem Header="Item 2" />
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>

</Window>

enter code here
```

Comment: This is a nice start, but it wouldn't be that simple in reality. The 'new' tab would flow very differently than the other items (which are handled by the tab panel). I think it would be difficult or even impossible to get an item outside the tab panel to behave like an item inside it. This is my main apprehension about retemplating. Still, thanks for the example.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose the first one:

so you have a collection of `TabViews` where every, if it's the last, when activated creates a new one and injects it before itself.

What about styling: if you want to make it part of UI, you can do it also after. That is the strong part of `WPF`.

So in general solution becomes kind of merge of both of the solutions you were talking about. 
Nothing can stop you to make style template for the last `TabView`  in the collection and apply it *only* to it.

Hope this helps.